# Process в Java не закрывает файл после компиляции

Tags: java, spring, файлы, javac

Проблема в следующем: я использую класс Process, полученных их Runtime.getRuntime() выполняю команду `javac -cp ...;... ... ...` для компиляции двух файлов с зависимостью от библиотек (ниже представлен код) и так как они мне нужны после комплияции небольшое количество времени, то желательно все эти скомпилированные файлы удалять, но появилась проблема в том, что Process блокирует скомпилированные файлы и не дает ничего с ними сделать, пока я не остановлю приложение.

Перепробовал всё, что касается закрытия чего-либо — не помогает. Всё равно при попытки с ним что-то сделать получаю `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: src\main\resources\classes\12bad837-9d23-43ba-ac43-c80eda1dca1b\Upper.class: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.` `System.gc()` кстати говоря иногда помогал, но не всегда. Во всяком случае использовать его постоянно не хочу.

Ниже код, который это делает.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "javac -cp " + modulesDirectory + "junit.jar;" + modulesDirectory + "hamcrest.jar "
        + className + " " + testClassName
);
```

Comment: Когда получаете эту ошибку процесс уже остановлен? Похоже, что просто пробуете удалять, когда процесс все еще жив

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте.

```
process.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
process.waitFor() - do the current thread to wait until the process dont terminated
process.destroy(); // - kill the process
process.destroyForcibly()-forcibly kill the process
```

Comment: Уже пробовал, не работает.

Comment: а если стоп этот процесс, затем  запустить новый, удаляющий этот?? , т.е. создать еще один отдельный класс , который будет удалять программу.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что имеется ввиду. Запустить новый Process, который удалит файлы через командную строку, а не через Java код?

Comment: //////////// да)

Comment: такая же история

Comment: тогда по завершении компиляции, и отработки программы, скомпилировать и запустить еще одну, которая будет удалять первую

Comment: проблема в том, что это сервер) он не должен перезапускаться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124113/discussion-between-nordfox-and-ulxanxv).

Answer (score 0):

такой вариант пробовали??

```
process.destroy();

File file = new File(C:\\...)
file.delete();
```

Comment: хотя технически ОС не даст, заниматься самоуничтожением))

Comment: я так делаю FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(path);

Comment: стоило дополнить свой предыдущий ответ вместо создания нового ответа.